# Duplicated functions formula

Tags: functions

Please help me to find $f(x)$ here.

I can't take $\frac{x-1}x$ as $t$ . So what should I do?

$$f(x) + f\left(\frac{x-1}x\right) = x + 1$$

$f(x) =$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$, then by simple calculations $(g \circ g)(x)=\frac{-1}{x-1}$ and $(g \circ g \circ g)(x) = x$.

Writing the given identity for $x$, $g(x)$, and $(g \circ g)(x)$ respectively gives:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
f(x) + f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) = x + 1 & \quad (1)\\
f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) + f\left(\frac{-1}{x-1}\right) = \frac{x-1}{x} + 1 = \frac{2x-1}{x} & \quad (2) \\
f\left(\frac{-1}{x-1}\right) + f(x) = \frac{-1}{x-1} + 1 = \frac{x-2}{x-1} & \quad (3) \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Adding $(1)+(3)$ and subtracting $(2)$ gives:

$$
2 f(x) = x + 1 + \frac{x-2}{x-1} - \frac{2x-1}{x} \\
f(x) = \frac{x^3-x^2-1}{2x(x-1)} \quad \text{for} \;\;x \ne 0, 1
$$

The values at $x \in \{0,1\}$ must satisfy $f(1)+f(0)=2$ but cannot otherwise be univocally determined from the given condition alone.